# Swift proper use of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have an application where is Label - Textfield. Many of users clicking on label and hope they will edit the UITextField. What is proper implementation of this problem? Should I create a button that will register touch and it will programmable click on textfield?
How can i archive this?

[image]

Comment: Are you performing any action while clicking on row?

Comment: that is not a row. That is label and uitextfield in view...its just cosmetics.

Comment: no .... UILabel + UITextField in UIView

Comment: put the label as hint

Comment: Hint? what it is and how can i archive?

Comment: Ok...you can use button instead much easier than adding gesture recog. to label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set `label.userInteractionEnabled = true`
2. `label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapFunc"))`
3. in your tapFunc: `textField.becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: Thank you! :-) I merged your answer with Ash and it worked :-)

Comment: Dont't you think having button with action method would be better solution.

Why to have label with tap gesture, If button has already touch dection with Action method ? Just Asking for clarification

Comment: I can't speak for Pan here, but I often use labels with gesture recognisers instead of buttons if I don't want any visual feedback when the item is touched. A button has a lot of extra code in it for things like images, changing states and so on. While it wouldn't hurt to use a button in most circumstances, the label is lighter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a gesture recogniser to the label, or to its containing view, making sure that the object is set to enable user interactions. Connect that to an @IBAction like this:

```
@IBAction func labelTouched() {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :-) I merged your answer with SaiCYLi and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions would be:

- change text color from blue to black for example and add a colon.
- add a hint inside your `TextView` so that your users can determine where to click
- place your label as a hint inside the `TextView`